# assign variable from bash mulitline timer output

Tags: bash, output

How can I assign a variable to this multiline bash countdown timer output:

```
seconds=10
    start="$(($(date +%s) + $seconds))"
while [ "$start" -ge `date +%s` ]; do 
    time="$(( $start - `date +%s` ))"
printf '%s\r' "$(date -u -d "@$time" +%S)"
done
```

and display the results with an:

```
echo -e $(timer_output)
```

syntax all in one line?

such as:

```
echo -e Script will exit in $(timer_output) seconds.
```

what I have now:

```
echo -e "\e[5m\e[1;31mScript will exit in:\e[0m\e[25m"
    seconds=10
    start="$(($(date +%s) + $seconds))"
while [ "$start" -ge `date +%s` ]; do 
    time="$(( $start - `date +%s` ))"
printf '%s\r' "$(date -u -d "@$time" +%S)"
done
```

Thank you Terrance for a more elegant solution.  Here is how it turned out with some color and it executes cleanly:

```
seconds=10
for ((i=${seconds};i>=0;i--)); do printf "\r\e[5m\e[1;31mScript will exit in $i seconds...\e[0m\e[25m"; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you Terrance.  seconds=10
for ((i=${seconds};i>=0;i--)); do printf "\r\e[5m\e[1;31mScript will exit in $i seconds...\e[0m\e[25m"; sleep 1; done ``` works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by assign the `timer_output` variable in a line that is constant.  It would be better to use a `for loop` with the `printf` and the `\r` in your line so that it keeps looping and printing the same line over and over until the time as been met.

Example

```
seconds=10
for ((i=${seconds};i>=0;i--)); do printf "\rScript will exit in $i seconds."; sleep 1; done
```

[image]